# docker-compose up fails for nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am getting the following error when I run docker-compose up:

```
backend_1_a5b5a2caf6fc | 2019/04/28 21:40:49 [emerg] 1#1: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
backend_1_a5b5a2caf6fc | nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
...
...
production_backend_1_a5b5a2caf6fc exited with code 1
```

Here is my Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**default.conf:**

```
fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm levels=1:2 keys_zone=laravel:100m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$query_string";

server {
   listen 80 default_server;

   root   /var/www/public;
   index  index.php index.html;

   client_max_body_size 5M;

 ...
 ...
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./nginx
    depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../../src:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
...
...
```

Comment: Share entire `default.conf` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have not setup ssl correctly (you're missing a server certificate). Since you have mapped port 80 and not 443 in your docker-compose i assume you're not going to use SSL.

Simply remove the following line in your `nginx.conf` to disable ssl:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

be sure to rebuild and restart your nginx container.

Comment: did you rebuild the container? please check that you config is in place. you can dump the current nginx config with `nginx -T` (you need to be in the container). is there any ssl?

Comment: Btw. The error indicates where the wrong ssl conf is. Does the error show the same file/line as before?

Comment: Looks like rebuilding few times fixed the issue. Thank you. Not sure why the first rebuild didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other server listening on port 443.Try to delete all symbolic links from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled except this one server you want to make work

Answer (score 0):

But, if someone need to use SSL, this error means that your `server` section is missing `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` declarations. You need to have a `.crt` and a `.key` file to run with ssl.

It should looks like

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen 443 default_server ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;

  ... other declarations

}
```